# Proxy $PORT value from create-react-app in a child directory

Tags: heroku, environment-variables, port, create-react-app

I'm working on a repo which is serving a create-react-app from a node endpoint. So, the react app is nested as a child directory:

```sh
.
├── Procfile
├── frontend
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── build
│   ├── package.json <---- "proxy": "http://localhost:$PORT" 
│   ├── public 
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── App.css
│   │   ├── App.js
│   │   └── // etc...
│   └── .env <----- frontend env file, removed PORT value from here
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── server.js
│   └── // etc...
├── .env <--- backend env file, PORT=9000 for node
├── static.json
└── yarn.lock
```

With port value removed from the .env file, CRA runs on port 3000. If I hardcode port 9000 instead of $PORT, then the proxy works properly in development.

However, when deploying to production, I want the frontend to proxy Heroku's dynamic port number, this is one example:
[image: Heroku's variable port number]

Heroku seems to ignore the port value even if I intentionally define it in the env in their website, with a value of 9000.

My question is how do I define the proxy on the frontend without having CRA to instance at that port number, e.g. apply PORT=9000 in the frontend .env but have CRA load at port 3000.

I've tried defining the port number in the script, while making sure that I've defined PORT=9000 in the frontend env:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "export PORT=3000 && react-scripts start",
```

CRA will load at 3000, but I get a proxy error:
[image: could not proxy error]

Comment: Wouldn't you want your React app served by the Node server on the same port, to avoid cross-origin issues going between the frontend and backend?

Answer (score 5):

Heroku doesn't let you chose your port, but rather allocates a port for your app to use as an environment variable. Read more [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/runtime-principles#web-servers)

> Each web process simply binds to a port, and listens for requests coming in on that port. The port to bind to is assigned by Heroku as the PORT environment variable.

- **Remove** all hardcoded `PORT` variables
- It's not ideal to use `$PORT` in your `package.json` file as you cannot add logic to it. In your nodejs app read the port variable like so:

  ```js
  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
  ```

  This will set the port variable to whatever is in the environment variable `PORT` and if it is not set, will default to 3000
- It is not efficient to serve a production app with CRA
- **Don't** run two servers for react and nodejs, instead use your nodejs app to serve a production built react app

  ```js
  const express = require('express')
  const path = require('path')
  const app = express()
  // All your other routes go here
  app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'client/build'))) // this must be the last one
  ```

  **NOTE:** This is assuming your react app is built inside `client/build` relative to your project root
- The proxy setting is **only for development** convenience and will **not** work if the app is not served by CRA
- Make heroku build your react app during buildtime with:

  ```sh
  npm --prefix client run build # or if you use yarn
  yarn --cwd client build
  ```

  in your **outer `package.json` file**'s build script
- You start script is going to run your nodejs server:

  ```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/server.js",
    "build": "npm --prefix client run build"
  }
  ```
- Don't commit your `.env` files to heroku, instead set environment variables directly using `heroku config:set KEY=VALUE` if you have heroku cli or use the dashboard settings

  **NOTE:** Do this before pushing your code to have these variables accessible during buildtime of the react app

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for!